# Did the Rebel Army in Star Wars have any in-canon rank and squad insignia?

Tags: star-wars

Question is pretty much as it says in the title. According to online sources, the Rebel military used a command structure not dissimilar to that of modern armies. A squad of nine troopers was commanded by a Sergeant, aided by a Corporal. Four squads made a platoon, commanded by a Lieutenant. 4 platoons made a company, led by a Captain and so on.

Officers in the alliance military wore dice pips to designate their rank - a Lieutenant had a single pip, a Captain had two. However, I can find no information on what designated a Sergeant or Corporal.

Troopers would also presumably have worn a patch or insignia to show what squad and/or platoon and/or higher level units they belonged to. But I can't source any information on this at all.

Do we have any detail on NCO insignia and unit designation symbols in the Rebel army? If not canon, legends will be fine - so long as it's referenced in a known once-official source.

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_command_insignia

Comment: @Valorum If you look at the page - which I already had, as mentioned in the question - you'll see it doesn't give insignia for sergeants or corporals. Nor does it mention squad, platoon or other relevant insignias.

Comment: Indeed, hence why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: @valorum ah! Ok - didn't know if you were downvoting for lack of effort. Don't know why I got one.

Comment: [This Legends section](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Rebel_command_insignia/Legends#Sleeve_patches) of the article Varlorum highlighted might give some insight into the insignia used.

Answer (score 9):

### Rebel Alliance Ground Forces have ranks & insignia, but they are not all detailed...

**Canon**

As linked by Valorum, there are a number of different ranks. [Canon material](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rebel_command_insignia) on Wookieepedia only gives us a brief look at Officer ranks (detailed in [Star Wars Rogue One Rebel Dossier](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484780795) and [Star Wars: Rogue One: The Ultimate Visual Guide](https://www.dk.com/us/book/9781465452634-star-wars-rogue-one-the-ultimate-visual-guide/)), which are indicated through dots on a plaque. As shown in the Wookieepedia article, in descending order:

- General

[image: General Insignia]

- Colonel

[image: Colonel Insignia]

- Commander

[image: Commander Insignia]

- Major

[image: Major Insignia]

- Captain

[image: Captain Insignia]

- Lieutenant

[image: Lieutenant Insignia]

There is no information on Enlisted ranks in either the Legends or Canon, so over to speculation...

**Speculation**

As shown by several screenshots of rebel soldiers in the [Battle of Hoth](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Do7GqTh5SMk), most enlisted and specialist had 3 by 3 patches on their right arm (These three pictures courtesy of Wookieepedia):

[image: Rebel trooper #1]
[image: Rebel trooper #2]
[image: Rebel trooper #3 (inside Echo base)]

It can be assumed at this point that all the troopers in this trop
A Rebel technician with an orange and red square on his 3x3 insignia:

[image: Rebel technician]

After re-watching the Battle of Hoth, it appears that a common enlisted rank is one red (bottom row, first cell) and one blue square in the center (saw this rank a number of times, in all occasions it appeared that soldiers with this patch were taking orders from others.) This screenshot shows several different ranks at once (labelled for reference):

[image: ![Rebel Soldiers]

From watching this shot, my speculation is that Numbers 1 and 4 are either troopers/corporals, Number 2 is a Non-Commissioned officer (Sergeant/Sergeant Major/Warrant Officer), also known as an NCO, and No 3 is another enlisted rank either slightly above or below Numbers 1 & 4, possibly in a support role (a trooper/corporal, possibly a machine gunner, medic, etc.) This additional shot shows an enlisted rank shouting to press forward:
[image: Rebel trooper #4]

It can only be speculated at this point that this trooper is another type of NCO due to there being a solid column of blue on his patch (similar to trooper Number 3 in the previous screenshot.) Another possibility is that these patches are [Tactical recognition flashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tactical_recognition_flash), patches worn on the sleeve to indicate which regiment/battalion the soldier is from (worn by British army soldiers.)

Please note that this later section is speculation and only the top section about Officer ranks are Canon- This later section is all up for debate. :)

Comment: great start - if you can list the source that the wiki references that would be better, otherwise the wiki is little more than fan-opinion

Comment: @NKCampbell which source are you talking about, all of them or any in particular?

Comment: any of them. All you are citing is the wiki, which I could go edit right now to say something entirely different :). In other words, a valid wiki answer will actually point you to the real source (ie - actual canon material, website, book, etc...). For instance, the insignia information in the wiki is listed as being sourced from a visual dictionary (canon print material), Ideally, you would directly cite that, but at least indicate that is the source the wiki *states* is it's source. Etc....

Comment: @NKCampbell Ok thanks, I'll be working on sourcing